# What should I change so that Chrome not opens New Window every time when this code triggers

Tags: c#

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace TallyWhatsappsender
{
    public class Class1
    {

        OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver chrome_driver = null;
 
        public String InitProcess(String contact,String file_route,String title,String chrome_binary)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file_route))
                {
                    return "Error : Attachment not found!";
                }
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "chromedriver.exe")))
                {
                    return "Error : Chromedriver.exe executable not found!\n chromedriver.exe file is missing\n update or reinstalling may fix the problem";
                }
                var chrome_driver_service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "chromedriver.exe");
                chrome_driver_service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept;
                if (File.Exists(chrome_binary))
                {
                    chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = chrome_binary;
                }
                chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome_driver_service, chromeOptions);
                IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chrome_driver;
                foreach (string ct in contact.Split(','))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct.Trim()))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(ct.Trim().Length != 12)
                    {
                        if (!(chrome_driver is null)) chrome_driver.Quit();
                        return "Error : Invalid contact number-" + ct;
                    }
                    chrome_driver.Url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + ct.Trim();
                    try
                    {
                        chrome_driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
                    }
                    catch (NoAlertPresentException e1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]")));
                    }
                    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //sending file
                    IWebElement file_open = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span"));
                    javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", file_open);
                    chrome_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='file']")).SendKeys(file_route);
                    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    wait2.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/span")));
                    IWebElement file_send = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/span"));
                    javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", file_send);

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    //sending text
                    IWebElement typebox = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"));//:chrome_driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class ='_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text']"))[0];
                    typebox.SendKeys(title);
                    IWebElement text_send = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span"));
                    javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", text_send);
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
                //chrome_driver.Quit();
                return "Process finished";

            }
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    if (!(chrome_driver is null)) chrome_driver.Quit();
            //    return ex.Message;
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code for exporting a PDF file from tally and send it through Whatsapp Automatically.
I am facing a problem :
Every time I use this option a new tab of chrome opens and closes after sending file, because of new window it asks me to login to whatsapp every time , I think it will sort out if it do not close after sending file or when I activate it , it goes automatically to the previously opened Web.Whatsapp.com so that I will not need authentication each time.
please help me out into this .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome_driver_service, chromeOptions);` a new tab opens.

Try separating the initiating process and the sending process.
For example, your `InitProcess` method could look like the following:

```cs
public InitProcess(String chrome_binary)
{
    try
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "chromedriver.exe")))
        {
            return "Error : Chromedriver.exe executable not found!\n chromedriver.exe file is missing\n update or reinstalling may fix the problem";
        }
        var chrome_driver_service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "chromedriver.exe");
        chrome_driver_service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept;
        if (File.Exists(chrome_binary))
        {
            chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = chrome_binary;
        }
        chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome_driver_service, chromeOptions);
        return "Intiated";
    }
}
```

And then you could add a `Send` function:

```cs
public String Send(String contact, String file_route, String title)
{
    try
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chrome_driver;
        foreach (string ct in contact.Split(','))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct.Trim()))
            {
                break;
            }
            if(ct.Trim().Length != 12)
            {
                if (!(chrome_driver is null)) chrome_driver.Quit();
                return "Error : Invalid contact number-" + ct;
            }
            chrome_driver.Url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + ct.Trim();
            try
            {
                chrome_driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]")));
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
            {
                continue;
            }

            //sending file
            IWebElement file_open = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span"));
            javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", file_open);
            chrome_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='file']")).SendKeys(file_route);
            WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(chrome_driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait2.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/span")));
            IWebElement file_send = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/span"));
            javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", file_send);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //sending text
            IWebElement typebox = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"));//:chrome_driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[class ='_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text']"))[0];
            typebox.SendKeys(title);
            IWebElement text_send = chrome_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span"));
            javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", text_send);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return "Process finished";
        }
    }
}
```

Now you call `InitProcess` only once at the beginning of you program and `Send` every time you want to send the file.